# Can we build an Image Editor in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make an Image Editor app in Flutter, adding a frame to an image an emojis and after that saving it to local storage, any tutorial or idea?

I tried using CustomPainter + render to texture but didn't get it how it can solve my problem

Comment: use [PictureRecorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PictureRecorder-class.html)

Comment: your question is broad but you can use https://github.com/skkallayath/photofilters  for image filters

Comment: @pskink Is there any tutorial on how to use PictureRecorder to add a frame to an image the documentation is too complicated.

Comment: @Ggriffo I don't want to add filters I want the user to choose among a number of frames to add to their uploaded image and have a png image as output

Comment: too complicated? Its just: "Records a Picture containing a sequence of graphical operations. To begin recording, construct a Canvas to record the commands. To end recording, use the endRecording method."